# Could not allocate dup blob fd

Tags: java, google-maps, marcadores

[image: Imagem com os bitmaps personalizados renderizados]

Tenho aproximadamente 1,5 mil marcadores em um mapa que estão sendo mostrados através de clusters para não sobrecarregar o aplicativo. estes marcadores atualmente são mostrados como **BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker()**

No entanto, quando modifico o código para cada ponto mostrar um **bitmap personalizado com valores sobre os marcadores**, apenas alguns poucos aparelhos apresentam este erro, entre eles **LG K10 LTE** e Alguns **Motorolas**. Na maioria dos aparelhos funciona normalmente.

Quando utilizo esta função, antes de terminar de renderizar todos os 1500 marcadores, trava com o seguinte erro:

**"Could not allocate dup blob fd."**

Em pesquisas sobre este erro, me parece que trata-se de um estouro de memória e que devo armazenar estes marcadores em cache LRU, mas não estou conseguindo fazer isso em conjunto com os clusters.

Alguém já passou por isso ou tem alguma ideia/sugestão para solucionar este problema ?

Segue abaixo o trecho do código renderizador dos bitmaps:

```
public class OwnRendring extends DefaultClusterRenderer<MyItem> {

    OwnRendring(Context context, GoogleMap map, ClusterManager<MyItem> clusterManager) {
        super(context, map, clusterManager);
    }

    protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(MyItem item, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {

        markerOptions.snippet(item.getSnippet());
        markerOptions.title(item.getTitle());
        markerOptions.anchor(0.33f, 1f);
        markerOptions.infoWindowAnchor(0.33f,0f);

        int cor = (item.getPublico() ? cfgCorPostoPublico : cfgCorPostoPrivado);
        String preço = item.getTitle().substring(item.getTitle().length() - 5);

        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(createMarker(preço, cor)));
        super.onBeforeClusterItemRendered(item, markerOptions);

    }

    protected boolean shouldRenderAsCluster(Cluster cluster) {
        return cfgCluster && cluster.getSize() >= cfgClusterMin;
    }
}

@Override
public void onCameraIdle() {mClusterManager.cluster();}

private Bitmap createMarker(String text, int color) {
    View markerLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_marker, null);

    ImageView markerImage = markerLayout.findViewById(R.id.marker_image);
    TextView markerRating = markerLayout.findViewById(R.id.marker_text);
    markerImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.pin_shadow);
    markerImage.clearColorFilter();
    markerImage.getDrawable().mutate().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY );
    markerRating.setText(text);

    markerLayout.measure(
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    markerLayout.layout(0, 0, markerLayout.getMeasuredWidth(), markerLayout.getMeasuredHeight());

    final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            markerLayout.getMeasuredWidth(),
            markerLayout.getMeasuredHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    markerLayout.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```